# Should I create separate SQL Server database for each user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, database-schema

I am working on Asp.Net MVC web application, back-end is SQL Server 2012.

This application will provide billing, accounting, and inventory management. The user will create an account by signup. just like http://www.quickbooks.in. Each user will create some masters and various transactions. There is no limit, user can make unlimited records in the database.

I want to keep stable database performance, after heavy data load. I am maintaining proper indexing and primary keys in it, but there would be a heavy load on the database, per user.

So, should I create a separate database for each user, or should maintain one database with UserID. Add UserID in each table and making a partition based on UserID?

I am not an expert in SQL Server, so please provide suggestions with clear specifications.

Please inform me if there is any lack of information.

Comment: Why not a separate server for each user :) (only kidding), Read up on some basic techniques for database design (Simply google it). One table should be enough to hold data for all the users. have a UserID column in that table to identify each user uniquely and use that UserID in any other tables where you have to reference that user.

Comment: Do you meant separate database ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple schemas versus enormous tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340721/multiple-schemas-versus-enormous-tables)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Plese do not mark it duplicate. This question is more elaborative and the scenario is changed. My question is specific to sql server, the solution could be different on other database server technology. You have not described what DBMS you are using. This is more specific and different by your question. Please consider

Comment: Underlying principles of multi-tenant architecture don't depend on which dbms you're using. Paper from Microsoft is linked in the duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DB per user is what happens when customers need to be able pack up and leave taking the actual database with them. Think of a self hosted wordpress website.  Or if there are incredible risks to one user accidentally seeing another user's data, so it's safer to rely on the servers security model than to rely on remembering to add the UserId filter to all your queries. I can't imagine a scenario like that, but who knows-- maybe if the privacy laws allowed for jail time, I would rather data partitioned by security rules rather than carefully writing WHERE clauses.

If you did do user-per-database, creating a new user will be 10x more effort. While INSERT, UPDATE and so  on stay the same from version to version, with each upgrade the syntax for database, user creation, permission granting and so on will evolve enough to break those scripts each SQL version upgrade.

Also, this will multiply your migration headaches by the number of users. Let's say you have 5000 users and you need to add some new columns, change a columns data type, update a trigger, and so on. Instead of needing to run that change script 1x, you need to run it 5000 times.

Per user Dbs also probably wastes disk space. Each of those databases is going to have a transaction log, sitting idle taking up the minimum log space.

As for load, if collectively your 5000 users are doing 1 billion inserts, updates and so on per day, my intuition tells me that it's going to be faster on one database, unless there is some sort of contension issue (everyone reading and writing to the same table at the same time and the same pages of the same table). Each database has machine resources (probably threads and memory) per database doing housekeeping, so these extra DBs can't be free.

Anyhow, the best thing to do is to simulate the two architectures and use a random data generator to simulate load and see how they perform.

Comment: I like your description about security purpose. I have to be careful while i am writing sql queries. If there is a large team then mistake of any one programmer can cause of big issue for whole organization. Thank you for your worthy description on both terms. It helped me to make decision quickly in a minute.

Comment: But don't forget, different security containers just slows hackers down. If I can guess the admin password and do sql injection, I can still browse other databases. If it's different instances, then running 5000 instances will bog down the server. If these are physically different servers with air gaps, that's pretty secure but wasteful of money. Real banks tracking real money still used databases with tables shared by many users. So it isn't the road you want to go down without some remarkable justifications.

Comment: Then what will you suggest me, What should i do in this case

Comment: Create a schema where you user gets a unique id, rows in the transaction table each have a unique id. Write lots of automated tests (using nunit or the like) to verify that queries run by users don't accidentally return someone else's data. To be more specific I'd need to understand your business model, e.g can users demand to pack up and go self host on another server, or is that a crazy scenario? (e.g. I'll never ask my bank for all my data so I can go set up my own bank, but this happens all the time for blogs and content management systems)

Comment: You are suggesting me to manage all users in one database. User can ask for his data. In this case we can create a temporary database with only his data and make available to him and then delete it. If we create one database for all users, what would happen with performance ? can you please provide some description on that.

Comment: All users want to see their data someday. I meant, do they want the ability to take a SQL .BAK file and restore it to their own SQL server, or do they just want maybe an excel file with all their transactions. The former favors 1 db per user, the later scenario favors many-users sharing one db. If your users are the mail man and grandma, then it's silly to think they will host their own app. If the user base is 5000 small businesses, most with an IT department, yeah, they might want the flexibility of their own db.

Comment: Yes, it is possible that my user can ask me to host their database on there own Database Server. In that case my system would be in a major fault and i have to say "No" for this. If there is 5000 database in my application then we can manage 5 servers and the load could be transmitted to other servers. I can bear increased coast but i cant compromise with performance.

Comment: Ah, that's a key fact now. Okay, then it's just a question of scale & manageability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282033/how-many-is-too-many-databases-on-sql-server SQL Server (and probably a regular server) can cope with a lot of databases, the constraint is going to be the tooling to support multi-tenant (you won't be able to open SSMS and make a manual change to 5000 databases-- it would have to be scripted and automated). If that isn't possible, then you're previous idea of shared everything with an export script will be far easier to maintain.

Comment: It is possible, i have prepared my own table and field documentation. i keep record of each change of database structure. I have a way to update each database independently. I can make changes with a manual generated script without using any tool. I think "Dont share anything" is more secure and scalable approach in my case.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an easy answer to give.

First, there is logical design to be considered. Then you have integrity, security, management and performance (in this very order).

A database is a logical unit of data, self contained. Ideally, you should be able to take a database, move it to another instance, probably change the connection strings and be running again.
All the constraints are database-level. No foreign keys can exist referencing some object outside the database.
So, try thinking in these terms first.

How would you reliably prevent one user messing up the other user's data? Keep in mind that it's just a matter of time before someone opens an excel sheet and fire up queries on the database bypassing your application. Row level security in SQL Server is something you don't want to deal with.

Multiple databases mean that all management tasks should be scripted out and executed on all databases. Yes, there is some overhead to it, but once you set it up it's just the matter of monitoring. If a database goes suspect, it's a single customer down, not all of them. You can even have different versions for different customes if each customer have it's own database. Additionally, if you roll an upgrade, you can do it per customer, so the inpact will be much less.

Performance is the least relevant factor here. Of course, it really depends on how many customers and how much data, but proper indexing will solve these issues. Scale-out is much easier with multiple databases.

BTW, partitioning, as you mentioned it, is never a performance booster, it's simply a management feature, allowing for faster loading and evicting of data from a table.

I'd probably put each customer in separate database, but it's up to you eventually to make a decision for yourself. Hope I've helped some with this.

Comment: I agree with you. The security and performance both are major factors. I can't compromise with it. However i can bear increased cost. Thank you for your valuable suggestion.