# Multi tenancy - MongoDB vs SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, database

Based on our requirement we need to have one database per account as we cannot have a single database. So we were thinking about multiple database on the SQL Server and based on my research we can have appx 32,000 database on single database instance but the resource limit will be reached far sooner.

[How many is too many databases on SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282033/how-many-is-too-many-databases-on-sql-server)

Another point was to use no-sql database like MongoDB. As far as I know we can create database per account with different database name.

I wanted to check reference to resources used by MongoDB, do I need more ram, processor and lots of servers for the architecture.

We are looking to have about 10,000 databases max on a server. Can that work on the a single mongodb server?

If you do have similar architecture currently running, please do share.

Comment: Why do you need one database per account on the same server?  What "requirement" specifies this unlikely need?

Comment: yes we need to store our client data on a separate database, just in case due some bad code selected wrong client id from the database and since the only data in the database belonged to that client, the damage was not as bad as it could have been.

Comment: ...unless the bad code selected the wrong *database*. Whether it's the database or the client id that you can mess up - it's the same thing, just a different name. I'd even be *more* worried about selecting the correct connection, because of connection pooling, dependency injection and thread-affinity - probably harder to manage than getting the query right. (Unless you're doing *both*, that might be a bit safer indeed).

Comment: Thanks - we thought database mapping will be done at one point in data access, so they are less chances of choose the wrong database. I will keep in mind of single database but currently we want to know reference to which option is better between mongodb and sql server with multi-database.

Comment: While Mongo is a terrific database for JSON type data you know that almost everything about it is very different that a relational database? That the query language is not SQL? That if you know SQL that you will have to go through a learning curve not only regards to syntax but also approach?